# How to create HTML table from JSON in .sjs?

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I would like to format single JSON file into simple HTML-based table
(e.g. tr,td) inside sjs without using any libraries.
Suppose if my json file saved as variable, how should I write?

I guess I should start with the following,
xdmp.setResponseContentType("text/html");
but am not sure how can I return my properties stick with HTML tags.

Comment: https://mlu.marklogic.com/ondemand/index.xqy?q=%28Role%3ADeveloper%29%20AND%20Concept%3AJavaScript  and https://mlu.marklogic.com/selfpaced/ would be a good place to start.

Comment: Maybe loop through the JSON with either `fn.concat` or `fn.tokenize` to add html & table tags to the properties into a new variable, then return that variable.